# Read value in hbs script from server

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using `handlebars` view method with `node.js`. I try to send string to the view html page, and read its value in `<script>`. But I get en error:

Server:

```
res.render('weekly', {
    test: 'TESTING_SCRIPT_HBS',
});
```

hbs file:

```
<script>
    varib = {{{test}}};
</script>
```

As I run it I get ther error:
`weekly:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: TESTING_SCRIPT_HBS is not defined`.

I understand why this errors occurs, but how can I fix it so that `{{{test}}}` will be a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following solution

```
<script>
    varib = "{{test}}";
</script>
```